# PHP check if cookie value equals another variable

Tags: php, cookies

I have created a cookie with a filmvalue. now i need to check if the cookies value is equal to the same filmvalue or to another value.

```
if(isset($_COOKIE[votecookie])) 
    { 
    echo "Sorry You have already ranked this film <p>"; 
    header("location: films.php?id=$id");
    exit();
    }
```

If the filmvalue is equal to the filmvalue already voted on then do the above code. but if the film is not voted on then do some other code.

is there a way to do something like this:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE[votecookie] && $cookiefilmvalue = $film)) 
    { 
    echo "Sorry You have already ranked this film <p>"; 
    header("location: films.php?id=$id");
    exit();
    }
```

Comment: fist, try replacing `=` with `==` in your `if` clause

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Erm, yeah...

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['votecookie']) && $_COOKIE['votecookie'] == $film)
```

Also, make sure you stick quotes around the elements, it stops PHP throwing a warning like:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant votecookie - assumed 'votecookie' in...
```

Comment: thank you! i fixed the error, it's my first time using cookies so sorry for this noob question.

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. You have misplaced brackets
2. You are assigning something with `=`, not checking for equality with `==`

Use this

```
if(isset($_COOKIE[votecookie]) && $_COOKIE[votecookie] == $film)
```